# Too many blood tests

Tags: probability, multiple-comparisons

In medicine, lab results are usually "normal" if within two standard deviations.  If I were to order 20 random tests, would it be safe to assume that one "normal" result could fall outside the "normal" range?  I am trying to get students not to order a battery of tests and consider the risks of having to pursue a "false positive" test.  Testing should be more specific to assess for a possible condition.

Answer (score 1):

That test implicitly has an alpha (false alarm rate) of .05. It's true that you would expect 1 in 20 lab results from someone with exactly "normal" blood to appear "abnormal". The solution is not to avoid taking more blood tests; it's to adjust your alpha. There are a variety of methods to account for multiple comparisons; common ones include the Bonferroni correction and the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure. You can use these to assess whether someone really does have abnormal blood after multiple tests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've described, I don't think it is a safe assumption to say that. In your example, you are not looking at a situation that is random; you are starting with a patient whose result you are assuming should be normal.

When you start asking questions of the form, "What is the probability of X, given that ... ?", you are getting into Bayes' Theorem. In your example, the assumption that the result should be normal (that is, that this would be a false positive) is what puts you in the territory of Bayes' Theorem.

To make this argument for your students, you would be better off talking about sensitivity and specificity. There are some very nice medical examples with Bayes' theorem that will allow your students to calculate the probability that a patient with a positive test result has a condition, based on the prevalence of the condition and the accuracy of the test.

Answer (score 0):

Subject to the other responses here, it also depends on how far away from normal the result is and the potential consequence of the test being correct.